# Problems when adjusting time series for seasonality with seas function in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have an issue when I try to adjust my quarterly time series dataset for seasonality in R. I have loaded in the dataset 'ASPUS' to R and specified it's date by using the following code:

```
ASPUS <- read.csv(file = "ASPUS.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
ASPUS$DATE <- as.Date(ASPUS$DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

The head of the dataset looks like this:

```
        DATE     ASPUS
1 1963-01-01 100.00000
2 1963-04-01 100.51813
3 1963-07-01  99.48187
4 1963-10-01 101.55440
5 1964-01-01 101.55440
```

The purpose of the dataset is to analyze it as a Time Series. Therefore, I use the ts function to create a time series object:

```
ASPUSts <- ts(ASPUS, frequency = 4, start = 1963)
```

However, this function returns negative numbers within the date column like this:

```
         DATE     ASPUS
1963 Q1 -2557 100.00000
1963 Q2 -2467 100.51813
1963 Q3 -2376  99.48187
1963 Q4 -2284 101.55440
1964 Q1 -2192 101.55440
1964 Q2 -2101 104.66321
```

My problem then occurs in the next step, where I try to adjust for seasonality with the function seas:

```
ASPUS1 <- seas(ASPUSts)
```

Because I get this error:

```
    Error: X-13 run failed

Errors:
- Seasonal MA polynomial with initial parameters is
  noninvertible with root(s) inside the unit circle. RESPECIFY
  model with different initial parameters.

Warnings:
- Automatic transformation selection cannot be done on a series
  with zero or negative values.
- The covariance matrix of the ARMA parameters is singular, so
  the standard errors and the correlation matrix of the ARMA
  parameters will not be printed out.
- The covariance matrix of the ARMA parameters is singular, so
  the standard errors and the correlation matrix of the ARMA
  parameters will not be printed out.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can deal with these negative values or otherwise solve the problem so that I can seasonally adjust my dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?ts`:

> Description:
>
> ```
>  The function ‘ts’ is used to create time-series objects.
>
>  ‘as.ts’ and ‘is.ts’ coerce an object to a time-series and test
>  whether an object is a time series.
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>  ts(data = NA, start = 1, end = numeric(), frequency = 1,
>     deltat = 1, ts.eps = getOption("ts.eps"), class = , names = )
>  as.ts(x, ...)
>  is.ts(x)
> ```
>
> Arguments:
>
> ```
> data: a vector or matrix of the observed time-series values. A data
>       frame will be coerced to a numeric matrix via ‘data.matrix’.
>       (See also ‘Details’.)
> ```

Here, the key thing to note is: "*data: a vector or matrix of the observed time-series values*". I.e. you are not expected to enter the date vector as an input to `ts`.

This is the correct syntax for `ts`.

```
ASPUSts <- ts(ASPUS$ASPUS, frequency = 4, start = 1963)
```

In your example, `seas` is actually trying to seasonally adjust the time series of dates that get transformed to -2557, -2467, ... (side note: internally R counts dates as differences from 1970-01-01; that's why dates in the '60s appear as negative numbers).